# Admob error Updates to reporting and earnings data may be delayed?

Tags: admob

Updates to reporting and earnings data may be delayed. Time zone for dates and earnings: Pacific Standard Time. Time zone for conversions: India Standard Time.?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Is this an error? If so, where do you see it and what have you done to trigger it?

Comment: i cant see any add for production in that down that comment is coming?

Comment: Sorry, I am having difficulty understanding what you mean. Would you add a screenshot?

Comment: i mean to say in AdMob i don't have any add to publish i integrated perfectly still i cant see any add in AdMob

Comment: Hi i try that in another account i can see the add but in this account its not working please help me quick

Comment: **Would you add a screenshot** to your question? Thanks.